# Journey Builder - Multiple Exclusion Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

Firstly thanks to @Eliot Harper for giving the work around for Exclusion DEs in Journey builder.
[How to use an Exclusion Data Extension in a Journey Builder Send Email Activity](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166996/how-to-use-an-exclusion-data-extension-in-a-journey-builder-send-email-activity)

But is there a way to exclude 2 or more Data Extensions in Journey builder?

Comment: An or statement

Comment: @EazyE can you please give an example AMPscript please.

Comment: Its a basic logical operator. Here is link to ampscript guide doc: (https://ampscript.guide/logical-operators/) and the more confusing SFMC official docs: (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm)

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington ... It is very easy than I thought..... this article helped me to understand very easily... https://ampscript.com/using-an-exclusion-script-for-email-sends/